# Select the sum of a count in select statement where date between

Tags: database, oracle

I have a query that select the count of data from each day, I want to modify the query so it can get the data from a date between two dates

The first Query as follows:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY q.english_Name DESC) as id,
COUNT(t.id) AS ticket,
  q.english_name queue_name,
  ts.code current_status,
  COUNT(t.assigned_to)               AS assigned,
  (COUNT(t.id)-COUNT(t.assigned_to)) AS not_assigned
 ,trunc(t.create_date) create_Date
FROM ticket t
INNER JOIN ref_queue q
ON (q.id = t.queue_id)
INNER JOIN ref_ticket_status ts
ON(ts.id=t.current_status_id)     
GROUP BY q.english_name,
  ts.code
 ,trunc(t.create_date)
```

but when I modify it to :

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY q.english_Name DESC) as id,
COUNT(t.id) AS ticket,
  q.english_name queue_name,
  ts.code current_status,
  COUNT(t.assigned_to)               AS assigned,
  (COUNT(t.id)-COUNT(t.assigned_to)) AS not_assigned
 ,trunc(t.create_date) create_Date
FROM ticket t
INNER JOIN ref_queue q
ON (q.id = t.queue_id)
INNER JOIN ref_ticket_status ts
ON(ts.id=t.current_status_id) 
where t.create_date between '18-FEB-19' and '24-FEB-19'

GROUP BY q.english_name,
  ts.code
 ,trunc(t.create_date)
```

the output is

```
1   1   Technical Support Sec.  CLOSED  0   1   19-FEB-19
2   6   Technical Support Sec.  OPEN    4   2   18-FEB-19
3   1   Technical Support Sec.  OPEN    0   1   21-FEB-19
4   3   Network Sec.            OPEN    2   1   18-FEB-19
5   1   Network Sec.            OPEN    0   1   21-FEB-19
```

how can i get the total output of the days so that the output is:

> ```
> 1 7   Technical Support Sec.  OPEN    4   3   
> 2 4   Network Sec.            OPEN    2   2
> ```

Comment: Provide also the input data and the result you want to get.

Comment: if `t.create_date` is of DATE datatype, please, **PLEASE** don't use strings to compare to the date. Also, years have 4 digits; Y2K wasn't a pointless exercise! Instead, you should be doing something like `where t.create_date between to_date('18/02/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('24/02/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`, bearing in mind that dates have time portions, so that predicate will find dates of midnight on 24th Feb 2019, but won't find dates of 1 minute past midnight on the 24th Feb 2019; you'd need to do `< to_date('25/02/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` to get rows at any time on the 24th.

Answer (score 0):

When you `GROUP BY` in a query, your result set will include one row for every distinct set of values in your `GROUP BY` list.  For example, the reason you are getting two rows for the OPEN records for "Techical Support Sec" is because there are two distinct values for `TRUNC(t.create_date)` resulting in two groups and, therefore, two rows in your result set.

To avoid that, stop grouping by `TRUNC(t.create_date)`.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY q.english_Name DESC) as id,
COUNT(t.id) AS ticket,
  q.english_name queue_name,
  ts.code current_status,
  COUNT(t.assigned_to)               AS assigned,
  (COUNT(t.id)-COUNT(t.assigned_to)) AS not_assigned
--     ,trunc(t.create_date) create_Date
FROM ticket t
INNER JOIN ref_queue q
ON (q.id = t.queue_id)
INNER JOIN ref_ticket_status ts
ON(ts.id=t.current_status_id) 
where t.create_date between '18-FEB-19' and '24-FEB-19'
GROUP BY q.english_name,
  ts.code
--     ,trunc(t.create_date)
```